# Boost python not found when building cv_bridge under OSX

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, boost, mavericks, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having the problem that cv_bridge can't find my boost libraries although it must have found them for the packages before when installing hydro on OSX.
When I look into /usr/local/include I can see all the boost files and folders, also python.

What's the problem here?

When I print the output of my boost libraries it says none.
CMAkeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(cv_bridge)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS rosconsole sensor_msgs)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED python)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
message("Include dirs of boost: " ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
message("Libs of boost: " ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

Output:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1111 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.55.0

  Boost include path: /usr/local/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_python

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


Include dirs of boost: /usr/local/include
Libs of boost:
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165961/boost-python-not-found-when-building-cv_bridge-under-osx/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2014-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-05-18**:
That cmakelists.txt works as expected over here. What version of OS X are you on? Also, I would start by  `brew update`, `brew remove boost cmake`, `brew install boost cmake` to make sure nothing funky is going on with your installs.

**Comment by [CodePorter](https://answers.ros.org/users/18858/codeporter/) on 2014-06-12**:
Did you manage to solve this? I currently have the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recent changes with the homebrew boost formula removed python from being built by default. You will have to manually  `brew install boost --with-python` or `brew reinstall boost --with-python`. See https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/330

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on 2014-10-07**:
for now it is brew install boost-python

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-10-07**:
I just updated the rosdep rule for boost to include `boost-python`.